# Not able to compare my database password and input field password

Tags: mysql, node.js

My input password and database password are same then also function is returning false. Here compare method is not working properly.I am getting false in return everytime while I am providing correct password.

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {


              const username = req.body.username;
              const password = req.body.password;

          db.query('SELECT * FROM dataa WHERE username = ?',[username], function (error, rows, fields) {
              if (error) {
              // console.log("error ocurred",error);
              res.send({
              "code":400,
              "failed":"error ocurred"
              })
              }else{
                  // console.log('The solution is: ', results);
                  if(rows.length >0){

                    console.log(bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].password));

                      if(bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].password)){
                          res.send({
                          "code":200,
                          "success":"login sucessfull"
                          });
                      }
                      else{
                          res.send({
                          "code":204,
                          "success":"Email and password does not match"
                          });
                      }
                  }
                  else{
                  res.send({
                  "code":204,
                  "success":"Email does not exits"
                  });
                  }
              }
          });


})
```

Comment: How do you persist user(and password)? Do you store raw password or hashed?

Comment: If you did store the password as plain text you have to hash the password using `bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
  // Store hash in your password DB.
});` If that is not the case make sure your password is not padded with whitespace, trim the password first.

Comment: I have hassed password in database.

Comment: Not a valid BCrypt hash. giving such error.

Comment: @user10849358 Do you hash the password using the same bcrypt? If not, use bcrypt instead.

Comment: How to identify i have used same bcrypt.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having more than one username in your database which match it up with the username your are giving so it will try and match it with the first one but the password would be a different one ..

Comment: I have a single username in database.

Comment: Is your password properly hashed ?